# How to create large custom number types like u160 in Rust?

Tags: rust, casting

The [uX crate](https://docs.rs/ux/0.1.3/ux/index.html) simplifies creation of non-standard width integers but is unfortunately limited till u128.

From uX docs:

> When non-standard-width integers is required in an applications, the norm is to use a larger container and make sure the value is within range after manipulation.

However u126 is the max natively supported unsigned number type.

Edit: Earlier I mentioned adding a type check to u256. But Rust does not have a native u256.

Comment: I think llvm allow integer of any bits but I don't remember if Rust allow this feature or know how to use.

Comment: well, just create a wrapper around `u256` for example `struct u160(u256)`. But imo it is a bit weird since it will be much bigger than needed. Otherwise just implement it from scratch, `struct u160([20; u8])`

Comment: Why not use a libgmp wrapper?

Comment: For example: https://crates.io/crates/rug

Comment: How to mimic overflow behaviour of `u160` if `u256` is used in its place? Also if custom type `struct u160([20; u8])` is defined, how to perform operations like addition or multiplication?

Comment: @real_shardul, just copy the `std` API and implement it.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/library/core/src/num/uint_macros.rs

Comment: @Netwave That doesn't work. The actual integer operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, etc.) are all implemented with compiler magic, which you can't get without forking the compiler. The types aren't even defined in `std` (technically that file is a part of `core` but that's irrelevant, they aren't defined in `core` either), that file just contains implementations of some helper functions.

Comment: @Smitop, you can mimic the API, not actually do the compiler magic. For the operators you have traits already....

Comment: Also you can check how the uX crate does implement the other values: https://docs.rs/crate/ux/0.1.3/source/src/lib.rs, just try to use it to create your own.

Comment: Another example in the primitive types crate: https://docs.rs/primitive-types/0.10.1/src/primitive_types/lib.rs.html#38-42

Comment: Corrected my question. Rust has no native u256